# How can I get CSS rounded corners without rounding the border line?

Tags: html, css, border

I am using border-radius to round the corners of a div. I also have a border line along the bottom of the div. Like this:

```
<div style="border-radius: .5em; border-bottom: 1px solid black">Content</div>
```

However, I would not like the border line to have rounded edges. I would like the border line to be entirely straight. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: With a single <div> you cannot. You will need additional element.

Comment: You can use pseudo elements...you don´t need additional elemets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.inner {
  background:red;
  border-radius:5px;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}

.wrapper {
  display:inline-block;
  border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner"></div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use pseudo element (`::before`) to simulate the straight border

**CSS**

```
div{
    position: relative;
    border-radius: .5em;
    background: #ccc;
}

div:before{
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    display:block;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    height: 1px;
    background: #000;

}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/n1khc3bf/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="border-radius: .5em; border-bottom: 1px solid black">Content</div>
```

Use in this way

```
<div style="border-bottom: 1px solid black">
    <div style="border-radius: .5em;">Content</div>
</div>
```

Just insert a div inside and set border radius for the content

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you are looking for this:

```
border-top-left-radius: 0.5em;
```

JsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/pywdpLL0/1/

You can specify each corner border radius separately.
Hope this helps.